# How to add extra attributes to request body and insert into Database in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dto

Resquest body of my post mapping is as per

```
Class A{ 
    private String aa;
    private String bb;
    private String dd;
}
```

But my JPA Entity Should be

```
Class B{
    private String aa;
    private String bb;
    private String cc;
}
```

`private String cc;` comes based on the processing decision on `private String dd;`. How to handle this. Currently I am having only Class A  How do I map Class A to Class B?

Comment: so what is the porblem here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is request-body in JSON?

Comment: yes It is in JSON format

Comment: Please add an example of what you have tried so far. Lets' find out why it is not working

Comment: do you need any extra bean for processig the dd property?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a constructor to the class B:

```
    class B{
        private String aa;
        private String bb;
        private String cc;

        public B(String aa, String bb, String cc) {
            this.aa = aa;
            this.bb = bb;
            this.cc = cc;
        }
    }
```

Now, you can get values from A, process them, and create a new instance of B with the processed values.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any bean for processing the incoming `dd` property, then create Class B this way:

```
Class B{
    private String aa;
    private String bb;
    private String cc;

    @JsonSetter
    public void setDd(String dd) {
        cc = processDd(dd);
    }

    ... getters, setters, etc.
}
```

You can now use a Class B object as a method argument in your controller method with `@RequestBody`